# Task causing strange behavior in form_load event

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a task that runs in the form_load event of a usercontrol in winforms:

```
private void ucDeviceInsert_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Threading.Tasks.Task getTBox = System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            await AVeryLongRunningProccess();
        });

        pbImage.Image = Properties.Resources.Remove;

        getTBox.Wait();

        pbImage.Image = Properties.Resources.Insert;

        btnNext.Visible = true;

        tmrDeviceInsert.Enabled = true;
        tmrDeviceInsert.Start();
    }

 private void tmrDeviceInsert_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Next();
    }
```

I change the image of the picture box to inform the user the progress of the long running process. That part works fine, however the button doesn't show, and the timer never starts.  I've stepped through the code, and I can confirm that it is running without any problems, which makes this even more baffling.  Any ideas what would be causing this issue?

Comment: By the way, creating `getTBox` can be simplified to `var getTBox = AVeryLongRunningProccess();`

Comment: @Jacob no, that would change the behavior, the first synchronous part of `AVeryLongRunningProccess` would be run on the UI thread, `var getTBox = Task.Run(() => AVeryLongRunningProccess())` would be the simplified version.

Comment: That's true, but if it shortly goes into asynchronous, then that should suffice. You're right that if there's some synchronous CPU-intensive stuff at the front, that would not be wanted.

Comment: @Jacob Entity Framework is notorious for this, its `****Async()` functions all do model verification synchronously before starting the async portion which can cause a noticeable pause in the UI the first time you access a DbContext per AppDomain.

Comment: @broke You said that you can confirm that it is running without any problems but i wonder what thread is executing rest of the code after getTBox.Wait(); is it UI thread or some other thread ? May be you don't see anything because UI thread is busy ?

Comment: @Fabjan I'm not sure which thread it is running on.  How would I tell?

Comment: You can check value of Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId property to find out what thread is in use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Task.Run` is for pushing CPU-intensive work off the UI thread. Since you're calling an asynchronous method, I suspect it's not CPU-intensive.

So, you can just use `async` and `await`:

```
private async void ucDeviceInsert_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  pbImage.Image = Properties.Resources.Remove;
  await AVeryLongRunningProccess();
  pbImage.Image = Properties.Resources.Insert;
  btnNext.Visible = true;
  tmrDeviceInsert.Enabled = true;
  tmrDeviceInsert.Start();
}
```

Note that at the `await`, the UI is shown and the user can interact with it (that's the point).

Answer (score 0):

`getTBox.Wait()` is going to try to complete that task synchronously. Therefore, the rest of the code after it won't happen until *after* the task completes.

I'd think you don't want your task to run synchronously at all, but rather handle its completion asynchronously, something like this:

```
getTBox.ContinueWith(() => updateStatusInUI());
```

Comment: You really [should not be mixing ContinueWith](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/10/continuewith-is-dangerous-too.html) with async/await. just make the `Load` event handler async and do `await getTBox`

Comment: Haven't done winforms in a while. That is definitely better if supported!

Comment: The only reason `async void` is supported is so you can use async with event handlers desgned before async/await was invented.

Comment: `ContinueWith` is valid for cases where async methods are _not_ supported.

Comment: @Jacob if this method runs synchronously in a UI thread then it must block it. But it's been said that code run without any problems...

Comment: @Fabjan, OP never said it ran synchronously. In fact, if it's being awaited, it's obviously not all synchronous.

Comment: @Jacob quote from your answer : "Therefore, the rest of the code after it won't happen until after the task completes"... This sounds like some sort of synchronization isn't it ?

Comment: @Jacob Why would I want to handle the completion asynchronously?  Would I get an exception if I try and access UI components from the task?

Comment: You don't want to block the UI thread while the computation is occurring. And yes, if the callback updates UI components, you'll have to update it accordingly to perform on the UI thread.